# Fragment Within Fragment Causes Missing Fragment After Screen Rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I work with `fragment` in `fragment` and when I rotate screen I can't `findFragmentByTag()`:

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        showNewsListFragment();
 } else {
        mFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG); // null here
 }
```

And this code for adding fragment to fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
try {
     fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
       replace(R.id.container, mFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).show(mFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and when I try find fragment by tag I get null. Where is my fragment?

Comment: Would you happen to be overriding "onSaveInstanceState()" in your Activity or Fragment?

Comment: If you are, you need to call `super.onsaveInstanceState()` so the Activity/Fragment can save its state in the Bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Try to override the onCreate() method in fragment class
and call

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

so that it will maintain the state of the fragment when you rotate the screen

Comment: This will require he handle the screen orientation himself which is most likely not what he wants.